# error C1243 reported incorrectly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, warnings

I'm recompiling a C++ dll, where I have made 0 code changes, except to replace a library in the build, which also meant changing include references.

This is very much a work in progress and is incomplete, when I compile the dll I get so many errors in modules that seem to be completely inaccurate.

For example I get C2143 reported on the last line of:

```
    typedef void (nliSERVICE_PIN_CALLBACK) (nliPROGRAM_ID const * const pProgramId,
                                    nliNEURON_ID const * const pNeuronId,
                                    UINT8 const SubnetId,
                                    UINT8 const NodeId,
                                    bool const FromRouter);
```

I've hovered the mouse every type and all check out and all are valid in the project.  But for some reason I am getting this error, unless I am missing something the syntax is correct.

The project is being built with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.

I have no choice on the version or build.

Error message:
      Error 213 error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'const'

Comment: Also remember that hovering over a symbol may not be accurate. Intellisense is a totally separate compiler from the compiler that you use to build your code.

Comment: Check the symbol(s) before the `const` have all been defined.  This looks like a "run-on-error" and the compiler is making a best-guess at the problem.

Comment: I have, everything is valid, all the custom type definitions exist and I can access them by right clicking and "Go to Definition"

Comment: As @drescherjm said: just because Intellisense can see the symbols does not mean that the real compiler can.  Try using the symbols in a small piece of test code.

Comment: The headers are present in the project and are all in the same folder.  I haven't changed anything.